# Module results hangs console app

Tags: f#

```
module p1=
    let rec fn n acc = ...
    let result =  fn 999 0
```

It is called from a different module under the same namespace.  fn returns acc which is int.

This works in either case ...

```
let fnMatchProblem = function
    | 0 -> "Good bye."
    | 1 -> (p1.fn 999 0).ToString()
```

But here, I can't figure out why the latter case (1) does not ... control goes back to the console where it hangs.

```
let fnMatchProblem = function
    | 0 -> "Good bye."
    | 1 -> p1.result.ToString()
```

or

```
let fnMatchProblem = function
    | 0 -> "Good bye."
    | 1 -> (p1.result).ToString()
```

For other purposes, I would prefer to have p1 to always return an int.  The reason for p1.result is to have predefined inputs.

EDIT 1:
I have it narrowed down.
There are 20 modules each in this format ...

```
module p<n>=
    let function param = ...
    let result = function param
```

Regardless of the module called, all modules are being executed.  Hence, the app is not hanging but is taking a very long time to execute all modules.  Oddly though, the results returned are from the module actually selected for execution.

EDIT 2 ... resolution ... Thanks to Vandroiy:

```
let fnMatchProblem = function
    | 0 -> "Good bye."
    | 1 -> p1.result()

module p1=
    let rec fn n acc = ...
    let result () =  fn 999 0 |> string
```

Comment: My guess, a bug in the p1 module.  try changing result to just return a number, to see if you have made an infinite loop or similar

Comment: Can't reproduce. Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not guaranteed that values which the final program doesn't need don't get computed. The normal ways to expose results of expensive calculations in modules are functions and lazy values.

Function:

```
module p =
    // ...
    let calculateResult () = fn 999 0
```

Lazy:

```
module myModule =
    // ...
    let result = lazy (fn 999 0)
```

The results of lazy computations are accessed by calling `.Force()` on them. They ensure that the expensive calculation is only run once and only when needed. See also: [Lazy computations in F#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/lazy-computations).